# How to autofill the command line prompt obtained after logging into the remote machine using winrs

Tags: java, powershell, winrm

I have a requirement where I need to access the remote machine's powershell and execute a few scripts. I did the same via winrs and able to start the executing of the script. But when there is a prompt coming, I am not able to automatically enter the value and the program gets stuck at the prompt itself.

The following is the powershell code I have written:

```
'Joe' | winrs /r:remoteHostServer /username:admin /password:xxxxxx powershell -c "Set-Location C:\test; java test.java;`$user1 = Read-Host;"
```

The test.java should give a prompt to the user to enter the name. I want to enter the name "Joe" and hence I am passing that as stdin. But it is not entering the name. I am getting the below output:

```
Enter the name for user:java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
```

But when I am executing the test.java file manually everything is working fine.

Is my above way of passing the value right? Please guide me as I am new to powershell scripting.

Comment: I don't know that utility but you might try starting with the keyword `echo`

Comment: Hi @g00se, can you please say where should I give the 'echo' keyword?

Comment: At the beginning before 'Joe'

Comment: @g00se I did that but that didn't work.

Comment: Does it work if you run the command locally? `'Joe' | java test.java`

Comment: @g00se, the command in the question uses PowerShell's implicit output feature, so there's no need for `echo`

Comment: Yes, I was wondering if that might be the case. Is that feature present in all versions? Not my field really ;)

Comment: hi @mklement0, no the command `'Joe' | java test.java` didn't work locally also. It didn't enter any value for the prompt and threw the 'java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found' exception.

Comment: You've got a `Scanner` reading from stdin at the outset of the app? You would *have* to for it to respond to that (if 'auto-echo' happens). IOW it would *not* work if arguments to `test.main` are expected

Comment: @g00se, yes, this behavior is an integral part of PowerShell's output philosophy, and has always worked this way.

Comment: @RDX, this suggests that your problem is unrelated to both `winrs` and PowerShell: you need to investigate why your Java application doesn't read from stdin as you expect it to.

Comment: @mklement0 , in my case when I execute the java file manually it prompts for the user input and we enter that and press the "enter" key. Can't this be automated via powershell?

Comment: @RDX, if the application is designed to read user responses from stdin, your approach should work. Since it doesn't, you'll either have to modify the application, or - suboptimally - _send keystrokes_. However, I don't think that will work in _remote_ calls. If you cannot modify the application, see if it accepts command-line _arguments_ as an alternative to providing data interactively.

Comment: Hi @g00se, yes in our java code we are using the objects of the Scanner class. So manually running the java file is working perfectly. Only trying to automate running the java file it is not entering any value for the prompt.

Comment: As @mklement0 said, it might be the fact that you're remoting that's throwing stdin off, but you're saying *it's not even running locally*?

Comment: @g00se, yes running `'joe' | java test.java` also is not working

Comment: If it also doesn't work when prefaced with `echo` then you'd better post code that demos the problem